# Setting the height of 4 android button to the max of the 4

Tags: android, button

I have a fragment in which i am displaying 4 buttons, in those button I m displaying some texts that I m getting from my sqlite database, after any button click I m refreshing the text on the buttons by getting some other text from the db.
What i want is to resize the buttons and set each button's height to the max of the buttons new size (the height will depend on the lengh of the text that is displayed in the button).
How can I perform that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kickoff example:

```
  <LinearLayout 
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >

       <Button 
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"/>

       <Button 
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"/>

       <Button 
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"/>

       <Button 
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

More info - [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight).

Comment: u made a little mistake in the spelling of weight. but its a correct answer.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin thanks for noting. Without you I didn't know that it's correct answer ) (jk)

Comment: it doen't work cause I m using it inside a fragment, and it doesn't resize after I change the text, I want it to change after I change the text of any button.

Comment: Did you try invalidating the view so it refreshes the fragments part of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Put all 4 buttons in a linear layout where the `orientation="vertical"` and give them each a `layout_weight="1"` and a `layout_height="0dp"`. This will give you a each button having the same height. You can manage the overall height by adjusting the height of the linear layout. The linear Labour's height must be large enough to contain the buttons

Comment: It exactly my answer which was here 7 minutes ago. Is there sense to repeat it?

Comment: Mobile app didn't show your answer, probably occurred as I was typing in my answer.